# jquery keypress in input text restriction, i want it to allow A-Z and white space only but my code won't allow "Y" and "Z"

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, restriction

Actually I didn't code this, i just copy and paste it to try.

Here's the code.

```
$("#firstname, #lastname").keypress(function(event) {
  var inputValue = event.charCode;
  if (!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  $('#input').html(inputValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keycode for `y` is 121 and likewise the keycode for `z` is 122. Therefore if you want to include those in the range then you should change `inputValue <= 120` to `inputValue <= 122`.

However, you don't need to check the keycodes for this. I'd suggest using the regular expression `/[^a-z\s]/gi` (which is a negated character class that will match characters that are not `a-z` or whitespace - case insensitive).

You can simply replace these characters with an empty string and effectively remove them:

```
$("#firstname, #lastname").on('input', function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z\s]/gi, '');
});
```

Basic example:

```js
$("#firstname, #lastname").on('input', function(event) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z\s]/gi, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="firstname" type="text" />
```

Comment: ahh i see, that's why the y and z is not allowed because in the code it only accepts up to 120 ASC codes.. I actually use your code, because the code I used can accept "^" and "_" . I probably use your code. THanks :)